# Вызов конструктора С++

Tags: c++, ооп

Доброго времени суток.

```
class A{
int i_;
public:
    ~A(){
        cout << "A destr " << endl;
    }
    A();
    A(int i) : i_(i){
        cout << "My constr A " << endl;
    }
};


int main(){
A* p = new A;
}
```

В такой реализации исходник не компилируется.

А вот в таком виде всё работает

```
 class A{
    int i_;
public:
    ~A(){
        cout << "A destr " << endl;
    }
A(){}
A(int i) : i_(i){
    cout << "My constr A " << endl;
}
};


int main(){
    A* p = new A;
}
```

Почему так?

Comment: `A();` вы этим говорите что конструктор где-то есть. Потом линковщик (не компилятор) не может найти и будет ошибка.

Comment: Ошибки нужно прикладывать к вопросу, а код форматировать

Comment: Всем большое спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Потому, что в первом случае конструктор у вас объявлен, но не определён, во втором - все ОК.

С C++11 так же доступна следующая запись, разрешающая компилятору генерировать конструктор по умолчанию:

```
A() = default;
```

Answer (score 1):

Он компилируется, но не линкуется.

В первом случае у вас нет определения конструктора по умолчанию `A::A()` - только его объявление, так что нечего вызывать при создании объекта без параметров

```
A* p = new A;
```

Если изменить код на

```
A* p = new A(0);
```

или дать значение по умолчанию конструктору

```
A(int i = 0) : i_(i){...
```

выбросив `A();`, то все будет работать.